# is it correct? i hope someone can help me hehe

Tags: python

Write a Python program that will search for lines that start with 'F', followed by 2 characters, followed by 'm:' using the mbox-short.txt text file.
Write a Python program that will  search for lines that start with From and have an @ sign

My code:

```
import re

file_hand = open("mbox-short.txt")
for line in file_hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('From:', line):
        print(line)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to lack the actual regular expression that will find the result you are looking for. If I understand correctly, your aim is to find lines starting with F, followed by ANY two characters. If this is the case, you wish to print the line to the terminal. Let me guide you:

```
import re

file_hand = open("mbox-short.txt")

for line in file_hand:  #NB: After a new scope is entered, use indentation

    result = re.search("$f..", line)   #pattern, search string

    #$ matches character before the first in a line
    #. matches 1 occurence of any character

    if result.group() != "":  #access result of re.search with group() method
        print(line)
```

I trust you can follow this. If you need capital F, I will leave it as a homework exercise for you to find out how to do the capital F.

You can practice with regexp here:
https://regexr.com/

Or read more about it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhzKDrUiJVk

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't ask your question clear enough for everybody to understand. Also, insert your code for better readability ('Code Sample'). I already did that with your code, so you can have a look at that.

Comment: From: zqian@umich.edu
From: antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
From: gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
From: ray@media.berkeley.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu

Comment: the output of it